# AccessibilityManager Not Enabled But Passes If Statement

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I don't know what would be the proper title for my question. I don't have much detail also because this is what DV team told me so. There is a piece of code that we've added for talkback. But somehow one person from our Design Verification team passed that if statement without anything enable on Accessibility.

There is our if statement

```
 if (am != null && am.isEnabled()) {

            if(state == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "announce 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
                        .show();
            } else { 
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "announce" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
                    .show();
               }
        }
```

Is that possible ? They want me to fix it and there is nothing to fix about it. I've tried with 5 different devices but its fixed already. If it isn't a normal situation please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

[AccessibilityManager#isEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager#isEnabled()) checks for any accessibility service running on the device. This could be TalkBack, but there are other accessibility services.

[AccessibilityManager#isTouchExplorationEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager#isTouchExplorationEnabled()) should be used in combination to check for TalkBack.

```
if (am != null && am.isEnabled() && am.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
}
```

The reason accessibility manager might return enabled without TalkBack being on, is that other accessibility services might be running. Some apps make use of accessibility services to achieve other functionality, and it is not obvious that accessibility service is even enabled. For example, LastPass has an accessibility service used to pre-fill passwords for older devices not compatible with the latest autofill APIs.

Comment: thank your for your reply. One of verification team member told me, I had no anyother accesibility service running on but i do have this kind of problem. When I've asked from another team member he told me there is a accesibility service running on. That was the crash. As you mentioned another accesibility service caused to this and am !=null and am.isEnabled() wasn't enough.